# AnimeJS lagging

Tags: vue.js, anime.js

My problem is that the animation of Anime.js or the Waypoints from the library vue-waypoint are lagging my website, idk if  the animation is heavy , there are too many waypoints or is the element itself.The animation is quite simple, here is the code of the function:

```
  animateSections(element1,element2){
     anime({
          // MOVE ELEMENT RIGHT TO LEFT

        targets:element2,
        keyframes: [
          {
          opacity:0,
          translateX: 100,

          },
          {
          translateX: 0,
          opacity:1
          },
        ],  
        delay: anime.stagger(250) ,

        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        duration: 1500,
      })
         anime({
          // MOVE ELEMENT LEFT TO RIGHT
        targets:element1,
        keyframes: [
          {
          translateX: -100,
          opacity:0
          },
          {
          translateX: 0,
          opacity:1
          },
        ],           
        delay: anime.stagger(250) ,
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        duration: 1500,
      })
  },
```

This function fires when the screen of the user reach's certain viewpoint. And when it fires lags the entire website. All this code is in a component, i said this because all other animations don't lag the website and this is the only one that do this.
There are 1 Waypoint for each section.

Comment: The animation itself doesn't seem to contain any heavy animation (since it only animates `opacity` and `transform`, which do not trigger re-paints on any other elements in the page except the target elements). The only way this can be debugged is having a *runnable* [mcve] showcasing the issue, so that any potential fixes can be tested. If you need a multi-file node-like online environment, use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: OK, thx, i will try.